# Dynamically adding and removing checkbox and inputfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make it possible to add and/or remove inputfields and a checkbox (for a competition-page)

Even though, when I click on the add button, 2 inputfields gets added and when i click the remove button, only on of those disappear. What is the issue?

```
var InputsWrapper   = $("#answerDiv");
var AddButton       = $(".adaddnext"); 

var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
var FieldCount=1; 

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  {
FieldCount++; 
$(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="adinputfield83"><div class="checkaccept cacc1"><label class="option"><input type="radio" id="contestAnswersChk_'+ FieldCount +'" name="correct" class="validate[required]"><span class="checkbox"></span></label> </div><input type="text" id="contestAnswer_'+ FieldCount +'" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]"/><span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span></div></div>');
x++;

return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".adaddnextremove", function(e){ 
    if( x > 1 ) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--; 
    }
return false;
})
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="answerDiv">
    <div class="adinputfield83">
        <div class="checkaccept cacc1">
            <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" id="contestAnswerChk_1" name="correct" class="validate[required]">
                <span class="checkbox"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="contestAnswer_1" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]">
            <span class="font-entypo icon-plus adaddnext" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </input>                    
    </div>              
</div>
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks...

Comment: $(AddButton).click(function (e)  { replace as AddButton.click(function (e) . Same for everything

Comment: @balachandran ah yes, found the mistake :-)

Comment: Seems to work fine... What am I missing?: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/R3TLB/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, In my case I added the `add`-button with each line! How can I add a button after each input field, which adds only 1 additional inputfield?

Comment: Answer below... You needed another delegated event for the adds. I also converted your string-HTML to a simple template to make it easier to maintain (I think you will agree). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/R3TLB/2/

You needed a delegated event for your `add` buttons as well as the delete buttons.

```
var InputsWrapper = $("#answerDiv");

var x = InputsWrapper.length;
var FieldCount = 1;

$(document).on('click', '.adaddnext', function (e) {
    FieldCount++;
    var template = $('#template').html();
    template = template.replace(/{FieldCount}/g, FieldCount);
    $(InputsWrapper).append(template);
    x++;

    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", ".adaddnextremove", function (e) {
    if (x > 1) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    }
    return false;
})
```

### HTML (using template HTML in dummy script block):

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <div class="adinputfield83">
        <div class="checkaccept cacc1">
            <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" id="contestAnswersChk_{FieldCount}" name="correct" class="validate[required]" /><span class="checkbox"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="contestAnswer_{FieldCount}" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]" /><span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true">Del</span>
        <input type="button" class="adaddnext" value="Add" />
    </div>
</script>
<div id="answerDiv">
    <div class="adinputfield83">
        <div class="checkaccept cacc1">
            <label class="option">
                <input type="radio" id="contestAnswerChk_1" name="correct" class="validate[required]" /> <span class="checkbox"></span>

            </label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="contestAnswer_1" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]"> <span class="font-entypo icon-plus adaddnext" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        </input>
    </div>
    <input type="button" class="adaddnext" value="Add" />
</div>
```

### Notes:

Do not use `$('body')` to listen for delegated events. It can have odd side-effects with certain events (including `click`). Use a fallback of `$(document)` instead, if you do not have a closer non-changing ancestor to your dynamic elements. Really you should be using `$('#answerDiv').on('click'...` as that is the closest static ancestor (more efficient and more specific).

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined you variables as selector `$(...)` so you should use only var names: `AddButton.click()`

The code looks then:

```
var InputsWrapper   = $("#answerDiv");
var AddButton       = $(".adaddnext"); 

var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
var FieldCount=1; 

AddButton.click(function (e)  {
FieldCount++; 
InputsWrapper.append('<div class="adinputfield83"><div class="checkaccept cacc1"><label class="option"><input type="radio" id="contestAnswersChk_'+ FieldCount +'" name="correct" class="validate[required]"><span class="checkbox"></span></label> </div><input type="text" id="contestAnswer_'+ FieldCount +'" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]"/><span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span></div></div>');
x++;

return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".adaddnextremove", function(e){ 
    if( x > 1 ) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--; 
    }
return false;
})
```

or you can also define your variables as string, for example:

```
var AddButton = ".adaddnext"
```

then you can use it, as you did in your code:

```
$(AddButton).click(...)
```

Then is should look like:

```
var InputsWrapper   = "#answerDiv";
var AddButton       = ".adaddnext";

var x = InputsWrapper.length; 
var FieldCount=1; 

AddButton.click(function (e)  {
FieldCount++; 
InputsWrapper.append('<div class="adinputfield83"><div class="checkaccept cacc1"><label class="option"><input type="radio" id="contestAnswersChk_'+ FieldCount +'" name="correct" class="validate[required]"><span class="checkbox"></span></label> </div><input type="text" id="contestAnswer_'+ FieldCount +'" placeholder="Write possible answer" class="validate[required]"/><span class="font-entypo icon-circled-cross adaddnextremove" aria-hidden="true"></span></div></div>');
x++;

return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".adaddnextremove", function(e){ 
    if( x > 1 ) {
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
        x--; 
    }
return false;
})
```

Comment: If you put all this in a fiddle, you will realize it does not work because the question's HTML was incomplete (no add buttons per item). Those missing add buttons also need a delegated `on`. Read all the comments too.